# Snippet tidy breaks unquoted colors

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

```html
<body bgcolor = #FF0000>
</body>
```

Upon tidying the above code it becomes `<body bgcolor=# FF0000>` which shows black instead of red.

```html
<body bgcolor=# FF0000>
</body>
```

I usually add quotes around attribute values for my html, but I've accidentally messed up code on other questions before.